# Why Rails don't wrap select query into begin commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

It seems like Rails only use begin and commit for create and update query, some of my select query remains in Postgres in idle status, so why doesn't Rails wrap selects into begin and commit as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because transactions (sql wrapped in `begin` / `commit` / `rollback`) make sense only when you change the data, ensuring the process is atomic. For example, to ensure that if you withdraw money from one account they will be credited to the other one.

Select query can not change the data, hence transactions are pointless here.